# How to plot Mappings in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, linear-algebra

I don't know how to plot mappings in python, and by mappings I mean nonlinear mappings, for linear ones there is already [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/YCZa8TAH) that you can use it to visualize them, but I can't find a site or even a python script to visualize nonlinear maps, to understand what I mean by nonlinear maps here is this picture

[image]

It is from [3blue1brown](https://www.3blue1brown.com/), and actually it is a plot of the complex function `f(z)=z**2` but you can easily transform it to a map, which is `F(x,y)=(x**2-y**2,2*x*y)`

So my question is, what libraries should I use to plot these things in python?

Comment: That plot was created using [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) so it's probably worth giving that library a go (or the [community edition](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/)). Though these are for making animations.

Comment: i know that, but i don't want to do animation, i just want to get a picture @Alex

Comment: A picture is just one frame of an animation. There's an option `-so` that will save the final frame to an image and show it

Comment: He has a FAQ section on what he uses to create the animations and graphics: https://www.3blue1brown.com/faq#manim

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *tools*: do you want to plot it programmatically in Python? The way you ask this is maybe too vague.

Comment: Yeah that's what i want (I actually thought that I can plot it using matplotlib) i tried using manim but it turns out that it is a bit complicated @Wolf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at [Sympy's plotting capabilities](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html). It uses Matplotlib as a backend. It still takes a bit of work since you need explicitly specify each line:

```
 import sympy as sy

# Create symbolic function Fz = (x + i*y)**2:
x, y, t = sy.symbols("x, y, t", real=True)
z = x + sy.I * y
Fz = sy.expand(z**2)

# Create expressions for the grid lines:
x_lines, y_lines = [], []
for g_ in range(-5, 6):
    Fz_y, Fz_x = Fz.subs({x: g_/2, y: t}), Fz.subs({x: t, y: g_/2})
    x_lines.append((sy.re(Fz_x), sy.im(Fz_x)))
    y_lines.append((sy.re(Fz_y), sy.im(Fz_y)))

# Make the plot:
plt0 = sy.plot_parametric(*(x_lines+y_lines), (t, -5, 5), show=False,
                          xlim=(-3, 3), ylim=(-4, 4), axis_center=(-3, -4),
                          xlabel="Re", ylabel="Im")

# Adapt color for each line separately:
for c_, p_ in enumerate(plt0):
    p_.line_color = 'blue' if c_ < len(x_lines) else 'red'

plt0.show()  # do the drawing

# Access matplotlib backend (works only in interactive IPython shell):
ax = plt0._backend.ax[0]  # get matplotlib axis
ax.grid(True)
```

It gives:

[image: Plot of F(z) ) z**2]

Alternatively, you can use [lambify()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to convert a Sympy expression to a Numpy function, e.g.,:

```
Fz_np = sy.lambdify((x, y), Fz)
print(f"Fz(1, 2) = {Fz_np(1, 2)}")
```

Then you can draw the lines in Matplotlib the traditional way.

Comment: Good work but how can i turn the picture into squares instead of rectangles

Comment: Use ``ax.set_aspect(1)``  to ensure same scaling for x and y.

Comment: Just one more question, why you used 'g_/2', it's not realistic @Dietrich

Comment: Only for aesthetic reasons, i.e.,  so it would look more similar to the plot from 3blue1brown.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**: this is by no means a good solution, I am writing this answer for the purpose of you having an answer at all, no matter how good or bad

My approach is to create an image and treat each pixel as a dot on a graph by plugging in the x coordinate of the pixel into a function that returns a number that is checked against the y coordinate of the pixel.  If the result of the function is equal to the y coordinate, the pixel's color is changed.  I added a few options to customize the look of the graph.  Here is the function (it is only a prototype mean and is not at its potential efficiency, if you like this approach I can improve the code):

```py
from numbers import Number

def draw_graph(image, math_func, *,
               error=10,
               x_scale=1, y_scale=1,
               x_offset=None, y_offset=None,
               color=(0, 255, 0)):
    if x_offset is None:
        x_offset = image.width // 2
    if y_offset is None:
        y_offset = image.height // 2
    pxls = image.load()
    for x in range(image.width):
        for y in range(image.height):
            output = math_func((x - x_offset) / x_scale)
            if isinstance(output, Number):
                if output - error <= (image.height - y - y_offset) / y_scale <= output + error:
                    pxls[x, y] = color
            elif isinstance(output, tuple):
                for out in output:
                    if out - error <= (image.height - y - y_offset) / y_scale <= out + error:
                        pxls[x, y] = color
```

`image` is a pillow Image object, `math_func` is a function that takes in an integer (x) and returns a number or a tuple of numbers (multiple values), error is how close the output of the function has to be to the y coordinate of the pixel in order for it to be colored, and the rest of the arguments are self explanatory.  If `match_func` returns `None`, the function will ignore it.

Here is sample usage of the function (the images should show themselves at the end of the program):

```py
from PIL import Image
from numbers import Number
from math import sqrt

def third_power(x):
    return 0.01 * x**3

def one_over_x(x):
    return 1 / x if x != 0 else None

def idk(x):
    return sqrt(x*x - 3) if x*x > 3 else None

def draw_graph(image, math_func, *,
               error=10,
               x_scale=1, y_scale=1,
               x_offset=None, y_offset=None,
               color=(0, 255, 0)):
    if x_offset is None:
        x_offset = image.width // 2
    if y_offset is None:
        y_offset = image.height // 2
    pxls = image.load()
    for x in range(image.width):
        for y in range(image.height):
            output = math_func((x - x_offset) / x_scale)
            if isinstance(output, Number):
                if output - error <= (image.height - y - y_offset) / y_scale <= output + error:
                    pxls[x, y] = color
            elif isinstance(output, tuple):
                for out in output:
                    if out - error <= (image.height - y - y_offset) / y_scale <= out + error:
                        pxls[x, y] = color

img1 = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), "black")

draw_graph(img1, third_power, error=5, x_scale=3)
draw_graph(img1, one_over_x, error=3, x_scale=100, color=(255, 0, 0))
draw_graph(img1, idk, error=1, x_scale=3, y_scale=10, color=(0, 0, 255))
img1.show()

img2 = Image.new("RGB", (2000, 2000), "black")

draw_graph(img2, lambda x: x*x, x_scale=10, y_scale=2)

img2.show()
```

Please comment if I made a mistake on this answer, it's 3 a.m. and I can't resist a good challenge.  I hope you find this answer useful or creative.

Comment: You said that the images should show themselves at the end of the program, but they actually don't.

Comment: Weird, maybe img1.show() is platform specific.  Add the lines `img1.save("graph1.jpg")` and `img2.save("graph2.jpg")`

Comment: it doesn't show the image at the end of the program, but i can find the image in the file system, but it looks like it's not complete @Elan-R